# My air ticket is missing last name (surname) will this be a problem

Tags: air-travel

My agent booked a ticket with only first name and middle name
For example, my passport name
Last Name : Mishra
First Name : John sandeep

However my agent booked a ticket showing my middle name as last name
I.e., Sandeep/ John .No last name per passport.
I will be travelling  international flight.
Will this be a problem.

What are my option, also there is only 18 hors left for my flight

Comment: Don't delay to have errors corrected. You should contact your travel agent immediately upon seeing this.

Comment: The last name is typically the most important name. This will cause problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will almost certainly be a problem.

As the ticket has been issued by an agent, the agent is typically the only party that can change your ticket before the flight.

Often there is a fee involved, but if it is clear that the error is due to the fault of the agent, then it should be possible to have any fee waived.

My advice would be to contact the agent as soon as possible.